# How retrieve data in Combobox from h2 database in JBPM?

Tags: java, combobox, h2, jbpm

I'm working on JBPM standalone Business-central, I need to add Combobox in the form and that contains a list of some data from default database h2 to let users choose. how can accomplish that? I tried to edit java code and it's not worked, can anyone help? thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this [blog](https://pravinstechblog.blogspot.com/2020/07/how-to-load-data-dynamically-in-listbox.html) to populate the Listbox in the form.